# How to show that $f(x,y,z) = (1-x^{2})^{2}+z^{2}+y^{2}+yz$ is a convex function on $S =\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} < x\}$?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

[image]

Information:
In the previous problem I had to find stationary points and the Hessian matrix

and I found out that in the stationary points $(-1,0,0) $ and $ (1,0,0)$ were local minimums, and in the point $(0,0,0)$ was a saddle point. The Hessian matrix is:

[image]

Does it have something to do with this? I've never had to do this before, so I'm not really sure how to do it.

Comment: is it $x> \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 3}$

Comment: just take partial derivatives

Comment: Booldy's answer is incomplete. There are cross derivatives in $y,z$ to consider. And somehow your Hessian calc failed to obtain those, too.

Comment: I am going to correct the hessian matrix now, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac {\delta^2 f} {\delta x^2}=12x^2-4$$
$$\dfrac {\delta^2 f} {\delta y^2}=2$$
$$\dfrac {\delta^2 f} {\delta z^2}=2$$
$$\dfrac {\delta^2 f} {\delta z\delta x}=0$$
$$\dfrac {\delta^2 f} {\delta z \delta y}=1$$
$$\dfrac {\delta^2 f} {\delta x \delta y}=0$$
$$H=12(3x^2-1)>0,\forall x>\dfrac 1 {\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: This should not have been accepted, because without taking partial derivatives and computing the full Hessian you cannot verify convexity.

Comment: Ah I see! Something is wrong with my Hessian matrix XD

Comment: edited,thank you Michael Grant